# Faraday cage for 5G?

Tags: electrical-engineering, microwaves

I'm interested in making a faraday cage that will block both standard and 5G wireless signals-  essentially to make a tabletop box that people can put their phone in to be completely undisturbed, and safe from any sort of hacking.

I'm not sure how relevant most information on faraday cages is with 5G-  there is one more catch-

I'd like to put a wireless charging pad inside- which will generate heat.  If there were some way to vent the heat while still stopping a signal (some kind of baffle?) that would be ideal.  I'm not sure if that's at all possible.

I am a metalworker/ welder/ fabricator so I have access to and ability to work with a variety of materials.  Lead seems the best option although Id prefer not to be putting more of that out into the environment.

Enlightenment much appreciated.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for electronics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Copper mesh should work for any radio signals.

Comment: Lead is for blocking ionising radiation. For RF, copper or aluminium (or gold or silver) are preferred.

Comment: Just turning your phone off would be much simpler.

Comment: True.  But tell that to a teenager.  A psychologist has asked me to make this so clients could put their phone in a box without the separation anxiety they usually feel, which is especially alleviated if they can still see it.